# I need to establish communication between android device and a convertor which is connected through USB

Tags: android

Convertor connected to hardware through RS485 port

The convertor details are
VID(hex)-10C4,PID(hex)-EA60,Release version-0100,Product Description-CP2104 USB to UART Bridge controller

Actually I need to display data received from convertor on Android device and also edited/updated data should be transfer on convertor also

I have gone through some links:
http://hackaday.com/2012/02/22/android-3-1-devices-have-usb-host-mode-heres-how-to-use-it/http://android.serverbox.ch/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/android_industrial_automation.pdf

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: The easiest (software) approach would be to switch to a part like the FT232 for which there is already Android USB Host API example code floating around.  If that is not an option, then such code could be used as a starting point, and modified to account for the differences between the USB operations needed by the CP210x series vs the FT232.

Answer (score 1):

An application note, [AN809 - Integrating the CP210x in to the Android Platform](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/an809.pdf), has been released which may provide some guidance in getting your CP2104 device recognized by the system.

Comment: Perhaps - depending on the target Android device the poster has in mind - but this is the "traditional linux" kernel driver method which is only usable by platform developers (or consumers with "rooted" devices).  Android has subsequently gained USB Host APIs accessible by ordinary applications.  Although Android-unique, these are more akin to the "libusb" approach in that instead of developing and loading a kernel driver, userspace code (built into an Android Application) interacts with the peripheral at the level of USB transfers.

Comment: Thanks Chris - the [CP210x spec](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN571.pdf) is available and can be used in the case you mention, such as `UsbConnection` or libusb.